# How to get common field in ten tables with different field name

Tags: sql, mysql

I am having a common field in ten tables with different field name.

example:

**table1:**

t1_id        t1_location

1                  india

2                   china

3                  america

**table2:**

t2_id        t2_location

4                  london

5                  australia

6                 america

**Now my o/p should be:**

**location**

india

china

america

london

australia

How should i get that using mysql query.

thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide more information.

Comment: You'll likely need to provide more details on the problem to get a meaningful answer. One thing does spring to mind: if the fields are truly the same, then they should be named the same.

Comment: Are there foreign keys?  Do you mean you have table 1 with column A and that is identical to column B in table 2?  What do you want to find out - the names of the columns across the tables?  The common value?

Comment: exactly you are right azp74. But i need all the values except duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query the locations using [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/union.html), which will also remove duplicates:

```
Select t1_location As location
From table_1
Union
Select t2_location As location
From table_2
```

Sounds like it would be a better approach to store all locations in a separate table with ID, and refer to that IDs in your tables.